# View sent System Workflow Messages

Tags: civivolunteer, system-workflow-messages

Is there an easy way to view system workflow messages that have been sent? I want to confirm volunteers are receiving confirmation message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Transactional extension](https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional) adds bounce handling and click tracking, and creates activities for CiviCRM's transactional emails (i.e event registrations, contribution receipts, invoices, scheduled reminders, and so on).

It also creates an Activity for every type of Mail that is sent out, so easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can set CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG to the path to a log file and then also set CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG_AND_SEND in civicrm.settings.php to also have them go out as normal: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#changing-file-based-settings

On a busy site the file will grow quickly so don't leave it turned on.